# Create ethereum address starting from entropy

Tags: wallets, addresses, private-key, bip39

Yesterday i came across this amazing tool by Ian Coleman https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ .I was wondering if it was possible to reproduce a script in phyton that do the same thing. Which should be the process, after generating a casual 128/256 bit entropy, in order to transform the entropy into a seed phrase, into the private key, into the public key and finally into an **Ethereum** address?
Also, since i'm struggling to find good python libraries to do that, if you have any suggestion would be great.

NB: i just need to create an Ethereum addresses, not for any other coin like the Ian Coleman's tools.

Comment: There's a package bip39 in the python package index https://pypi.org/project/bip39/ (I haven't tried it yet).

Comment: Thanks @Ismael, appreciate. That seems to work properly for the first part of the process: i can correctly convert a byte sequence (entropy) to the seed phrase. I also found this package https://pypi.org/project/bip44/ that does the last part (creating pubkey, privkey and address from mnemonic).